# Shortest code to check if a number is in a range in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

This is how I checkout to see if a number is in a range (in between two other numbers):

```
var a = 10,
    b = 30,
    x = 15,
    y = 35;

x < Math.max(a,b) && x > Math.min(a,b) // -> true
y < Math.max(a,b) && y > Math.min(a,b) // -> false
```

I have to do this math in my code a lot and I'm looking for shorter equivalent code.

This is a shorter version I came up with. But I am sure it can get much shorter:

```
a < x && x < b
true
a < y && y < b
false
```

But downside is I have to repeat `x` or `y`

Comment: @NullUserException: Does that imply that `0` is in the interval `1 - 2`?

Comment: @Bergi Derp. OP, that was very wrong.

Comment: your shorter version is wrong http://jsfiddle.net/Fm39z/

Answer (score 23):

```
Number.prototype.between = function (min, max) {
    return this > min && this < max;
};

if ((5).between(4, 6)) {
    alert('worked!');
}

var num = 6;
if (num.between(5, 7)) {
    alert('still worked!');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jbabey/4jjRm/1/

Note that you need to surround number literals in parens, or the interpreter will think your property is a decimal point and blow up.

Comment: Obviously this will only work if you pass the numbers in the correct order.

Comment: @NullUserException: You can easily add that with the line `if(max<min) return this.between(max, min);`

Comment: It's a pretty solution but it's not advisable to modify native types/objects (call them whatever you want). There are a few articles on this topic, e.g. http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/

Comment: @Andris `Number` is not a DOM native object, it's a javascript native object. I think most people agree that extending javascript native objects (`Object`, `Number`, `Function`, etc) is fine.

Comment: I agree. Extending the object is the way to go. Cleanest and most efficient solution.

Comment: DOM or not DOM, you are modifying the default functionality. Of course it's easy to add custom methods to objects like Array or Number, but then you might switch to another codebase, which doesn't have that functionality and you'll get confused. There's a reason why jQuery doesn't do things the same was as Prototype did, although it could...

Answer (score 2):

If I had to do this a lot, I'd just write a function `inRange(a, b, x)` so it would be a short function call any time I needed it.  This way you could also make the function body slightly less obfuscated without worrying about its length.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the flexibility to test if a number falls between two numbers without first finding the minimum and maximum :

```js
let inRange = (num1, num2, numTest) => {
  [min, max] = [num1, num2].sort((a, b) => a > b);
  return numTest > min && numTest < max;
}
```

Testing from low to high:

```
inRange(1, 5, 3); // true
inRange(1, 5, 6); // false
```

Testing from high to low:

```
inRange(5, 1, 3); // true
inRange(5, 1, 6); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

I edited the code from above, because it doesn't make the sort well.
This is what worked for me perfectly (includes the range ends):

```js
var isNumberInRange = (num1, num2, testNum) => {
  var min, max;
  [min, max] = [num1, num2].sort((a, b) => a - b);
  return (testNum >= min && testNum <= max);
};
```