# Check if number is within range of target number

Tags: javascript

I would like to check to see wether a number is within 4 of a target number.

Currently I do this in the following manner:

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/o0b99yys/

```
var targetNum = 32;
var newNum = 31;

if ((newNum > (targetNum + 4)) || (newNum < (targetNum - 4))) {
  alert('Error: number must be within 4 or target');
} else {
  alert('Success: number is within 4 or target');
}
```

this seems a little amateurish. Is there a cleaner more professional way of doing this?

Comment: If it works, its professional

Comment: `Math.abs(targetNum - newNum) < 4` like this?

Comment: @Legionar, no, it really must be `&&`

Comment: This will do it: `Math.abs(targetNum - newNum) <= 4`

Comment: @Pamblam no! it cant be bigger and also lower!!! There must be `||`

Comment: If I use an `&&` the condition will never be met? it's one or the other, or am i missing something?

Comment: That's because the other operators are backwards too.

Comment: The best solution is in comments `Math.abs()` method.

Comment: @Grundy `<=`, because also 4 can be!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shortest code to check if a number is in a range in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806304/shortest-code-to-check-if-a-number-is-in-a-range-in-javascript)

Comment: I don't know how this question can get upvotes at all. You have a 6 line code with a if-statement. I mean wtf could someone do wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution looks better:

```
var targetNum = 32;
var newNum = 31;

if (Math.abs(targetNum - newNum) > 4) {
  alert('Error: number must be within 4 or target');
} else {
  alert('Success: number is within 4 or target');
}
```

Comment: If you copy&paste the solutions of other people, please, try to explain it and format with code tools

Comment: I didn't copy anybody's solution, I posted it also in the comments.

Comment: Ok! Sorry if I disturb you.

Comment: Thanks, exactly the kind of elegant solution i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```js
    var targetNum = 32,
        newNum = 31,
        target_range_max = targetNum + 4,
        target_range_min = targetNum - 4;

    if ( target_range_min <= newNum && newNum <= target_range_max ) {
     alert('Success: number is within 4 or target');
    } else {
     alert('Error: number must be within 4 or target');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this if u want simplified versions on that expressions:

```js
var myNum = 32;
var newNum = 31;

Math.abs(myNum-newNum)>4 ? alert('Error: number must be within 4 or target') : alert('Success: number is within 4 or target');
```